# Regular Expression (Java)

Tags: java, regex, string

How do I match the following string?

```
http://localhost:8080/MenuTest/index.action
```

The regex should return true if it contains "MenuTest" in the above pattern.

Cheers

Comment: Vinayak, this doesn't need a regular expression, this needs plain-vanilla string matching.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you don't need a regex?

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/MenuTest/index.action";    
boolean hasWhatImLookingFor = url.contains("MenuTest");
```

Comment: @Oscar - This is true. Fixed.

Comment: @karim: Now you have to use that lowercase name! :) s/URL.contains/url.contains/  otherwise it will be worst as it was before. BTW +1 for the "simple" approach answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check if "MenuTest" appears *at that specific position* (i.e. after the host/port), then you can use:

```
^https?://[^/]++/MenuTest
```

Comment: Nice and precise solution  :)

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines? (untested)

```
Regex r = new Regex("MenuTest");
r.search("http://localhost:8080/MenuTest/index.action");
System.out.println(""+r.didMatch());
```

Comment: eh? Regex isn't part of the standard Java API - Which 3rd party library is this from?

Comment: I didn't realize, but it's using com.stevesoft.pat. Doesn't really matter what regex package (you have to use one, since you say it's not part of the standard API) you use, the idea is the same, to match a single word in a string.

Comment: java.util.regex has been part of the Java library for around seven years. No need for a third-party library where the standard will do.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you seek is simply "MenuTest", without the quotes. Unless the question is more complex than it appears?